How to put Microprofile / OpenAPI annotations into interface for generating Swagger-file while keeping source-code clean
In Quarkus, I need to define an API that will result in a Swagger-UI JSON/YAML-File to give out to consumers.
This works as expected/documented by defining many annotations in the REST-endpoint. For example:
@POST
@Operation(summary = "creates a new product")
@APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "product creation successful")
@APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Server unavailable")
@Path("/")
@RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = {
    @ExampleObject(
        name = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_NAME,
        description = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_DESCRIPTION,
        value = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_VALUE
    )
}))
@APIResponse(content = @Content(examples = {
    @ExampleObject(
        name = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_NAME,
        description = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_DESCRIPTION,
        value = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_VALUE
    )
}))
@ResponseStatus(201)
public CreateProductResponse create(CreateProductRequest createProductRequest) throws ValidationException {
    return productManager.create(new RequestContext(1, 1), createProductRequest);
}

The REST-endpoint almost gets unreadable this way (this is one of the smaller examples).
My preferred way to solve this, would be to define an interface, that the REST-endpoint would implement.
Can somehow help me to...

... (a) find out if this is even possible.

... show me an example of how to define such an Interface in Quarkus


... (b) show me a better way to achieve my goal of having small/maintainable REST-endpoints while still being able to document the Swagger-UI API-definition close to the source-code.

What I would have expected to work (but does not, the annotations in the interface are completely ignored by the framework and will not find their way into the generated swagger-json/yaml file):
@Path("/api/v1/products")
public class ProductControllerV1 implements ProductApiV1 {

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Override
    public CreateProductResponse create(CreateProductRequest createProductRequest) throws ValidationException {
        return productManager.create(new RequestContext(1, 1), createProductRequest);
    }
}

@Tag(
    name = "Product Controller V1",
    description = "Product Operations, for testing many different use-cases"
)
@Path("/api/v1/products")
public interface ProductApiV1 {

    @POST
    @Operation(summary = "creates a new product")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "product creation successful")
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Server unavailable")
    @Path("/")
    @RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = {
        @ExampleObject(
            name = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_NAME,
            description = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_DESCRIPTION,
            value = CreateProductRequest.EXAMPLE1_VALUE
        )
    }))
    @APIResponse(content = @Content(examples = {
        @ExampleObject(
            name = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_NAME,
            description = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_DESCRIPTION,
            value = CreateProductResponse.EXAMPLE1_VALUE
        )
    }))
    @ResponseStatus(201)
    CreateProductResponse create(CreateProductRequest createProductRequest) throws ValidationException;


Can you try this in your REST Controller:
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProductControllerV1 implements ProductApiV1 {

    @Override
    public CreateProductResponse create(CreateProductRequest createProductRequest) throws ValidationException {
        return productManager.create(new RequestContext(1, 1), createProductRequest);
    }
}

Another way of maintaining the OpenApi documenation is by making use of the hybrid approach.
That means: you store openapi.yml in src/main/resources/META-INF and edit this file with the stuff that is hard to do in code with annotations, and you can add some simple annotations on your code and Quarkus will combine both results (giving code higher priority).

Hi @Serkan, thanks this worked! The ApplicationScoped Annotation in your example made the difference. There is one caveas though: The jakarta.ws.rs.POST annotation (or a similar ws-annotation like GET) must be present on the interface method. Otherwise its annotations will not be picked up. Thats something i can somehow live with :)

after fiddling a bit more with it, it seems that it only works well, when the jakarta.ws.rs.POST annotation (or a similar ws-annotation like GET), as well as the jakarta.ws.rs.Path annotation is present in both: the interface-method and the implementing method.

sadly this approach (interface for annotations) seems to be too unreliable for developers to use this in a day-to-day work. For example: The @ResponseStatus(201) only works when placed directly on the implementation-method, but not if placed on the interface-method, while it shows in swagger correct in both cases, but only returns 201 as method-call result, if placed on the implemention-method. Because of those inconsistencies (who knows what other annotations are working in such special ways) i will stick with the big rest-endpoint classes, and consider my question as still unsolved.

Try the hybride approach: copy the generated openapi.yml to META-INF folder and set the response code there. And remove the @ReponseStatus from your code.
